# Markerclusterer hide markers that aren't clustered

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Is there a way to hide a marker that isn't clustered? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I though about checking a mark value after clustering then setting it to null or maybe if a zoom level isn't 4. But not sure how to go about it.

Comment: To the person who downvoted - If you downvote a question, at least have the common decency to comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `visible`-property of the markers to `false`